# Call Stored procedure using Eloquent integrated with Ratchet

Tags: php, eloquent, ratchet

I am trying to build a Chat application using Ratchet and have integrated the Eloquent ORM in my application. I need to call a stored procedure, but my server script fails when it reaches the line of code where I'm trying to call the stored procedure.

I have included the 'DB' as:

```
use DB;
```

and trying to execute the stored procedure as:

```
DB::select("CALL getMessages(173, 0, 6)");
```

Is there something that I am missing. Please help.
Thanks,

Comment: We need to know the signatire of your stored procedure

Comment: `getMessages`(IN userId INT(11), IN lastMessageId INT(11), IN chatroomId INT(11))